# How to use singly-linked-list forEach(fn) function in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

**Description**

I am trying to use the `forEach(fn)` function of the `singly-linked-list` [node.js module.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/singly-linked-list)
My list `global.windows` contains `BrowserWindow` objects. On each `BrowserWindow` object I want to execute `webContents.send('refresh-pf');`.

**Attempts**

This version works but only exectues it on the first `BrowserWindow` object in the list:

```
global.windows.getHeadNode().getData().webContents.send('refresh-pf');
```

Now I wanted to use the `forEach(fn)` function. It has the following desciption in the documentation.

```
### forEach(fn) Utility function to iterate over the list and call
the fn provided on each node, or element, of the list
```

*First Attempt*

```
global.windows.forEach(getData().webContents.send('refresh-pf'));
```

This causes the following error.

```
Uncaught Exception:
ReferenceError: getData is not defined
```

*Second Attempt*

Because of the error I thought that the `forEach(fn)` function executes `fn` not on each node but on the data element of each node.

```
global.windows.forEach(webContents.send('refresh-pf'));
```

This however causes this error:

```
Uncaught Exception:
ReferenceError: webContents is not defined
```

**Question**

It seems like I am doing something completely wrong with that function. How can I execute `webContents.send('refresh-pf')` on each `BrowserWindow` obejct in my list?

Comment: you're using forEach wrong ... you seem to know the first argument has to be a function (fn in your question) - but you, instead, pass the result of calling a function as the argument, something like `global.windows.forEach(x=> x.getData().webContents.send('refresh-pf'));`

Comment: Thank you very much! That works perfectly.